# How to use Material design in KitKat like in new Google Play

Tags: android

I have searched how to use Material design in KitKat, but only answers were that it is not supported on KitKat. How it is possible that new Google Play Store utilizes the Material design on KitKat? Or maybe they use some other trick to add Material like experience?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Reading the Compatibility section of Android L Developer Preview might help you, Link as follows
http://developer.android.com/preview/material/compatibility.html#materialtheme

Comment: I've read the link and my question is how Google added Material look to Google Play despite the fact that on the Compatibility section we can find: "The material theme is only available in the Android L Developer Preview."